# Creating and linkin doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

Hi I have been trying to debug this piece of code for very long time but cant figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here, I am trying to copy two doubly linked lists(of different lengths) into a new one. However, when I return the newly made linked list, the nodes are not connected. Can someone tell me where have I done wrong?

```
struct PolyNode
{
    int coef;
    int expx;
    int expy;
    PolyNode* prev;
    PolyNode* next;
}

PolyNode* padd(PolyNode* a, PolyNode* b)
{
    PolyNode* c = new PolyNode;
    PolyNode* c_head =c;
    PolyNode* a_head =a;
    PolyNode* b_head =b;
    c->prev = nullptr;
    c->next = nullptr;

    PolyNode* c_next = c->next;
    PolyNode* c_prev = c->prev;

    while (a != nullptr)
    {
        c->coef = a->coef;
        c->expx = a->expx;
        c->expy = a->expy;
        cout << "\t\t copied c=" << c->coef << c->expx << c->expy << endl;

        if(a->next != nullptr)
        {
            c_next = new PolyNode;
            c_next->prev = c;
            c_prev = c;
            c = c_next;
            a = a->next;
        }
        else
        {
            c_next = new PolyNode;
            c_next->prev = c;
            c_prev = c;
            c = c_next;
            break;
        }
    }

    while (b != nullptr)
    {
        c->coef = b->coef;
        c->expx = b->expx;
        c->expy = b->expy;
        cout << "\t\t copied c=" << c->coef << c->expx << c->expy << endl;

        if(b->next != nullptr)
        {
            c_next = new PolyNode;
            c_next->prev = c;
            c = c_next;
            c_prev = c;
            b = b->next;
        }
        else
        {
            c_next = nullptr;
            break;
        }
    }

    c_next = nullptr;

    int sum = Polylength(a_head) + Polylength(b_head);

    for(int i =0; i< sum-1 ; i++)
    {
        if(c_prev == nullptr)
        {
            break;
        }

        c_next = c;
        c = c_prev;
        c_prev = c_prev->prev;
    }

    c_next = c;
    c = c_prev;
    c_prev = nullptr;

    sortPoly(c); //sortPoly is a function which sorts polynomials from largest to smallest exponents and sum them up if same exponents.
    return c;

}
```

Also I am not a very experienced programmer and I am trying to develop some good programming habits. Please suggest any common best practice for dealing with pointers and linked list. Thanks!
But the problem here is that even in the beginning of the function things go bad and I am returned a node that does not have any links to the next node.

[EDIT stuyckp] indented code properly and added a problem statement as last sentence.

Comment: common practice - use a debugger and post the output

Comment: I did, but it only gives me the first node after shifting the head to the other end.

Comment: It's hard to say something without having the code that compiles. But at first glance, you are not setting `c->next` when adding new node to `c`

Comment: Make a drawing, pointers are just arrows, datastructure instances are blocks, each time you change somehting in the code do the same thing on the drawing. Your bug will also show in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

This code is full of bugs, if you are learning to work with pointers you really have to go one step at a time and also make a drawing of what you do with your pointers. I did this to verify your code and the problems pop out pretty quickly.

Your basic error is that you seem to think that following :

```
PolyNode* c_next = c->next;
PolyNode* c_prev = c->prev;
```

will somehow create a variable that is still belonging to the c node, while in fact the value of c->next is just null and this value is copied in a new variable. Then if you change this new variable, you are not changing c->next at all.

I am not going to solve all your problems but this is a step in the right direction. Don't use all these temporaries, do this instead :

```
while (a != nullptr)
{
    c->coef = a->coef;
    c->expx = a->expx;
    c->expy = a->expy;
    cout << "\t\t copied c=" << c->coef << c->expx << c->expy << endl;

    if(a->next != nullptr)
    {
        c->next = new PolyNode;//make c's next point to a new node
        c->next->prev = c; //make this new nodes prev point to c
        c->next->next = nullptr; //make sure to indicate the end
        c = c_next; //now move c to the next position
        a = a->next; //now move a to the next as well
    }

    ...
```

I still don't like this code though, because if a and b were both null you would still allocate a new node. I would allocate within the while loop. and initialise c to null at the very start.

Your code is also doing way to many thinks which will make debugging and maintaining this crazy. That is also why there is so much copy paste code the while a loop and the while b loop are practically the same. Try to make some fine grained functions with good names that document what you are doing within them. padd for instance is a very bad name for this large function. It is not adding it is copying 2 lists and creating a new one from both of them.

This is not c++ either, it is just plain c. In c++ you would use a different approach where the behavior is added to the datastructure in the from of methods. I won't elaborate on this, I think you have enough to go on.

Comment: Thank you a lot on this.

Comment: Please mark as answer or upvote. That is the way SO works.